# I suggest that he study/studied medicine

Tags: tense, content-clauses

> I suggest that he **study/studied** medicine.

Suggest is the present form of verb. So according to it, the sentence should have *study* rather than *studied*. *Studied* is basically past form of the verb.

But the answer is **studied**. Any rules regarding this?

Comment: I have a hunch that it's from a test/exercise somewhere on the web. Is that right? If that's the case, the common advice applies: don't believe everything you see on the Internet. Chances are, you may know better than them. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the sense of the sentence is that you are giving advice to the person as to what to study, then "I suggest that he study medicine" is correct.

The sentence "I suggest that he studied medicine", to me, conveys a sense of a group of people speculating about what the person "he" refers to studied in the past, and that "I" am putting forward a guess that it was medicine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, which book says it's 'studied'?

You are using the present tense i.e. 'suggest'. The word 'study' cannot be in the past then.

> I **suggest** that he *<del>studied</del>* **study** medicine.

If you want to talk about the past tense, the advisory verb *suggest* will take 'should'

> I ***suggested*** that he **should** **study** medicine.

Comment: What do you mean by "If you want to talk about the past tense, the advisory verb suggest will take 'should'"? -- "suggested" needs "should"?

Comment: Yes, you are right. @DamkerngT. however, not mandatory. The structure looks better that way.